# Failing while appending variables to make HTTP calls

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

This works fine:

```
String url ="https://api.textlocal.in/send/?apiKey=kWu25t2352msjdfsrlo-1hSBOuZxB&sender=NEWJNY&numbers="+"6382551203"+"&message=Thanks for registering on newjourney,Your otp code is 3234");
```

But this doesn't:

```
String url =String.format("https://api.textlocal.in/send/?apiKey=kWu25t2352msjdfsrlo-1hSBOuZxB&sender=NEWJNY&numbers="+"6382551203"+"&message=Thanks for registering on newjourney,Your otp code is%s",Integer.toString(random));
```

I am trying to make HTTP calls and Fails while appending variable on it

Error thrown
**Bad url** (volley throws me this error).

Comment: Does your `random` value has a required length (I guess it should be 4 digits long)?

Comment: you minimally need to show what error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

I've compared the two lines provided and I guess there are 2 options:

1. (Most probably) you're missing a space before `%s` in your `String.format` string.

End of the first line is `Your otp code is 3234`.

End of the second line is `Your otp code is%s`. You have to change it to `Your otp code is %s` (note the space between `is` and `%s`).

2. Check that your `random` variable has a required length (I guess it should be 4, but you should know the business-logic better).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use retrofit to handle HTTP request.

Then just try this:

```
@Get("send")
public Call<Object> MyFunction(@Query("apiKey") String apiKey,
                               @Query("numbers") String numbers,
                               @Query("message") String message);
```